# How to freeze a swift application in Xcode7

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, delay

I would like to freeze/pause all functionality of my Tic Tac Toe app for 2 seconds just after it displays, "Player 1 is the winner", in a UIImageView. Currently it displays the message but only for a split second so it is impossible to see.

I have tried using the function:

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))),dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
```

but this does not seem to pause my application, it just delays the code that follows it. This is a problem as once the application pauses the user can still place game pieces on the game board.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you displaying the message?

Comment: Using a UIImageView

Comment: You don't want to freeze your app. You just want to show the image for few seconds.

Comment: Yes but how do I stop the user from placing unneeded game pieces while the image is being shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the user from interacting with the game board while you display the *winner* sign, set the `userInteractionEnabled` property of your UI elements to `false`.  Then use `delay` to set them back to `true` in 2 seconds.

Something like this:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Player1Wins")
board.userInteractionEnabled = false
delay(2) {
    imageView.image = nil
    board.userInteractionEnabled = true
}
```